# Product of continuous functions when domain is an arbitrary topological space

Tags: general-topology

Lets say we have two functions $F:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and
$G:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that both functions are continuous. Is it necessarily true that their product is continuous. I know that if $X$ is a metric space it is true and can be shown by a delta-epsilon proof. However, I do not see why it has to be true for an arbitrary topological space yet I cannot seem to construct a counterexample either.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It is clear the function. $X^2\to\mathbb R$  defined as $(x,y)\mapsto f(x)g(y)$ is continuous. Then the question becomes if the function $X\to X^2$ defined as $x\mapsto (x,x)$ is continuous.

Comment: Hint: First verify that the function $+: {\mathbb R}^2\to {\mathbb R}$, $+(a,b)=a+b$ is continuous. Then think about compositions of continuous functions.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at Kohan's hint and some other resources I figured out what I believe to be the proof. I will write it down in case anyone finds it helpful.

> Lemma: Let $F:X\rightarrow Y$ and $G:X\rightarrow Y$ be two continuous functions, $X,Y$ arbitrary topological spaces. Then $\mathcal{F}: X\rightarrow Y^{2}$ defined by $x\mapsto (F(x),G(x))$ is a continuous function.

Let $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$ be basis elements of $Y$. Then $U_{1}\times U_{2}$ is a basis element of $Y^{2}$. If $x\in \mathcal{F}^{-1}(U_{1}\times U_{2})$ that means that $F(x)\in U_{1}$ and $G(x)\in U_{2}$ or
$x\in F^{-1}(U_{1})$ and $x\in G^{-1}(U_{2})$. In otherwords $x\in F^{-1}(U_{1})\cap G^{-1}(U_{2})$ iff $x\in \mathcal{F}^{-1}(U_{1}\times U_{2})$. Since $F,G$ are continuous that means that $F^{-1}(U_{1})\cap G^{-1}(U_{2})$ is open. As such every basis element has an open preimage as needed.

Using this lemma and the fact that compositions of continuous functions are continuous we simply need to show that the multiplication map $*:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Let $\epsilon>0$. We want to show there is a $\delta$ such that when $||(x,y)-(a,b)||<\delta$
then $|xy-ab|<\epsilon$. By the triangle inequality we get
$$|xy+xb-xb-ab|<|xy-xb|+|xb-ab|$$
$$ <|x||y-b|+|b||x-a|$$

Edit:In addition, using the standard Euclidean norm, if $||(x,y)-(a,b)||<\delta$ then $|x-a|$ and $|y-b|$ are less than $\delta$.

We have three options for $\delta$. The first being $\frac{\epsilon}{2|b|+1}$ (Edit: wrote $\frac{\epsilon}{2|b|+1}$ to take care of the case where $b$ is 0 which will let $|x-a||b|<\epsilon/2$. The second is $\epsilon$ itself which lets $|x-a|<\epsilon$ or $|x|<\epsilon+|a|$ which gives rise to the third $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2(\epsilon+a)}$ which would set $|x||y-b|<\epsilon/2$. Pick the smallest of the deltas and this completes the proof.

Comment: Almost right. Just need to take care of the case $b=0$.